# MYSQL - SubSelect when FK does and doesnt exists

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

**Situation Overview**

The current question is a problem about selecting values from two tables **table A (material)** and **table B (MaterialRevision)**. However, The PK of table A might or Might not exist in Table B. When it doesnt exists, the query described in this question wont return the values of table A, **but IT SHOULD**. So basically here's whats happening :

The query is only returning values when A.id exists in B.id, when In fact, I need it to return values from A when A.id ALSO dont exist in B.id.

**Problem:**

Suppose two tables. Table **Material** and Table **Material Revision**.
Notice that the PK **idMaterial** is a FK in **MaterialRevision**.

**Current "Mock" Tables**
[image]

**Query Objective**

> Obs: remember these two tables are a simplification of the real
>   tables.

For each Material, print the material variables and the last(MAX) RevisionDate from MaterialRevision. In case theres no RevisionDate, print BLANK ("") for the "last revision date".

**What is wrongly happening**

For each Material, print the material variables and the last(MAX) RevisionDate from MaterialRevision. In case theres no Revision for the Material, doesnt print the Material (SKIP).

**Current Code**

```
SELECT 
    Material.idMaterial,
    Material.nextRevisionDate,
    Material.obsolete,
    lastRevisionDate
FROM Material,

 (SELECT MaterialRevision.idMaterial, max(MaterialRevision.revisionDate) as "revisionDate" from MaterialRevision  
    GROUP BY  MaterialRevision.idMaterial
 ) AS Revision

 WHERE (Material.idMaterial = Revision.idMaterial AND Material.obsolete = 0)
```

**References and Links used to reach the state described in this question**

[Why is MAX() 100 times slower than ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930331/why-is-max-100-times-slower-than-order-by-limit-1)

[MySQL get last date records from multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514532/mysql-get-last-date-records-from-multiple)

[MySQL - How to SELECT based on value of another SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970495/mysql-how-to-select-based-on-value-of-another-select)

[MySQL Query Select where id does not exist in the JOIN table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776668/mysql-query-select-where-id-does-not-exist-in-the-join-table)

> **PS** I hope this question is correctly understood since it took me a lot of time to build it. I researched a lot in stackoverflow and after
>   several failed attempts I had no option but to ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `JOIN` :

```
SELECT m.idMaterial, m.nextRevisionDate, mr.revisionDate AS "lastRevisionDate"
FROM Material m
LEFT JOIN MaterialRevision AS mr ON mr.idMaterial = m.idMaterial AND mr.revisionDate = (
    SELECT MAX(ch.revisionDate) from MaterialRevision ch
    WHERE mr.idMaterial = ch.idMaterial)
WHERE m.obsolete = 0
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437) is an explanation of what `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` are. (You will love them if you often cross tables in your queries)

As `m.obsolete` will always be true, I ommited it in the `SELECT` clause

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this query only returns the material with the MAX revision Date. When Actually I need to return everyMaterial and only the revision with the MAX revisionDate.

Comment: Strange. It shall return all obsolete `Material` that have at least one `MaterialRevision`...

Comment: It must return materials that also doesnt material Revisions

Comment: OK, so you might replace `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`. My bad, I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: Still only returns 1 value.

Comment: The problem seems to be " MAX(...)"

Comment: I figured out the issue. I Will mark your answer as correct after you edit it. I will post my answer so you can edit it. I really appreciate your answer. Without you, I wouldnt be able to solve it. Thanks a lot. Kudos for you Sir.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the left outer join instead of using the cross product.

You're query should be something like this:

```
SELECT idMaterial, nextRevisionableDate, obsolete, 
revisionDate AS lastRevisionDate
FROM Material
LEFT OUTER JOIN MaterialRevision AS mr On 
Material.idMaterial = MaterialRevision.id
AND mr.revisionDate = (SELECT MAX(ch.revisionDate) from MaterialRevision ch 
WHERE mr.idMaterial = ch.idMaterial)
WHERE obsolete = 0;
```

[Here](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/joins.php) you can find some documentation about types of join.

Comment: Sorry but this only returns one value.

Comment: Yes my mistake this only returns the row with the highest revisionDate.

Comment: I should use the max in the join as you did in your answer, now I edit mine